# External hard drive seen only when connected on boot

Tags: mount, external-hdd, automount, detect

Which info should I provide about hard drive?
It's a brand new Seagate 1TB 5400 rpm 2.5" put into a cheap Chinese USB 2.0 "Icy Box" external encasement.
It always gets "noticed" by Windows after a while (~30-40 secs after connection), but it only is "seen" by Linux (e. g. `lsblk`) after a reboot.

So after a reboot it's normally auto-mounted into `/media/mekkanizer/`

UPD: Here, some `dmesg` output.

```
[ 3443.260390] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 3443.404424] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1bcf, idProduct=0c31
[ 3443.404427] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 3443.404429] usb 1-1: Product: USB to Serial-ATA bridge
[ 3443.404431] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Sunplus Innovation Technology 
[ 3443.404432] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: FF1000FF03000000000000FDE5FF7E
[ 3443.406495] usb-storage 1-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 3443.406808] scsi host2: usb-storage 1-1:1.0
[ 3466.108873] usb 1-1: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
```

I feel like the problem is in the last line of it, but I have no idea how to prevent this "resetting of an usb device".

UPD2: I have 2 usbs on one side of laptop corpus and 1 on the other. Assuming that I tried the 3.0 hub (which *still* seems like a misidentification by `lsusb`, cuz 3.0 ports are all blue colored, AFAIK), I tried the lonely port on the other side, successfully.

```
mekkanizer@Inspiron-5767:~$ lsusb | grep 'root hub'
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So, the problem is half solved, kinda. Now, if anybody knows how to force normal usb 2.0 software (driver? module?) on the *3.0*
hub, which isn't really 3.0? Or, maybe, there is a way to *force copy* properties of one device into another, devices are just files, aren't they?

P.S.  Somehow I feel like 3.0 usb would have been mentioned in laptop's specification or on-corpus sticker (it's not).

Comment: From a terminal, does it show up in the output of sudo blkid ?  Does it have an entry in /etc/fstab to automount ?

Comment: @ubfan1 unfortunately, it will show up in both blkid and lsblk output only when actually detected after a reboot. But knowing the letter and number gives you no benefit, cuz it's auto mounted on boot anyways. And no, it's not present in /etc/fstab, but still detected and mounted by some ubuntu boot scripts. I have added an `lsusb` output to question now, maybe that will bring some light...

Comment: Where's the `lsusb` output? At this point it's probably redundant though because the `dmesg` output already contains all the relevant information. Could you please try to connect the USB drive case to a USB 2.0 port? Maybe the "cheap Chinese" manufacturer added a "broken" USB chipset that doesn't support USB 3.0 backwards-compatibility.

Comment: @DavidFoerster My dear, where did you get the info about 3.0? I have none! Also yes, `lsusb` output is just a little less verbose than dmesg's, it also gives no info on this "USB device reset using xhci_hcd", so I didn't include it

Comment: `xhci_hcd` refers to the [XHCI specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHCI) which is another name for USB 3.0. In this context it means that the Linux kernel thinks it's dealing with a USB 3.0 host controller. See the output of `lsusb | grep 'root hub'` or `lspci | grep USB`.